# if then till last row

Tags: excel, vba, arguments

I want that if cell in column e is not blank but cell in column i is blank then write unregister in column i or else write what ever written in column i.

Please help - I have used below code:

```
Sub Simple_If()

Dim lastrow As Long
 
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("e2:e" & lastrow).Value <> "" And Range("i2:i" & lastrow).Value = "" Then
        Range("i2:i" & lastrow).Value = "unregister"
    End If
       
End Sub
```

Comment: One could say that you need a `VBA` solution for the `Excel` formulas `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E1)),IF(ISBLANK(I1),"Unregister",I1),I1)` or better `=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(E1)),ISBLANK(I1)),"Unregister",I1)` , because they cannot be written into column `I`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 See below

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code was not working is because you can't get `.value` of a `.range` (`Range("e2:e" & lastrow).Value <> ""`). Instead, use a `for loop` to iterate through each cells value individually.

I have commented each line of the code below to help you understand what is happening.

To make this work, change `SO.xlsm` to the name of your workbook and `63649177` to the name of your worksheet.

```
Sub Simple_If()
    Dim WB As Workbook                                                                  ' workbook      - full name of the file containing data.
    Dim WS As Worksheet                                                                 ' worksheet     - worksheet within  workbook containing data.
    Dim lRow As Long                                                                    ' last row      - find last row containing data
    Dim i As Long                                                                       ' iteration     - used for loop
        
    Set WB = Workbooks("SO.xlsm")                                                       ' set the name of the  workbook here
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("63649177")                                                  ' set the name of the  worksheet here
    lRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row                                   ' find the last row of E in the WS object, not user defined.
    Set Rng = WS.Range("E2:E" & lRow)                                                   ' set the initial range
    
    For i = 2 To lRow                                                                   ' from line 2 to the last row, repeat this loop
        If WS.Range("E" & i).Value <> "" And WS.Range("I" & i).Value = "" Then          ' if E contains data and I does not then
            WS.Range("I" & i).Value = "unregister"                                      ' fill cell with "unregister"
        End If                                                                          ' end if
    Next                                                                                ' cycle through next iteration of loop
End Sub
```

Output

[image]

Comment: You can do better: OP is using the `F` column to calculate the last row because he doesn't know if the last cell (of the `UsedRange`)in either columns `E` or `I` will or will not be blank, but he knows that all cells in column `F` will have a value. You could post an image of the data before the code has run and include some data in the `F` column to demonstrate my previous point.

Comment: I've got it set to last row of E

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Rows

- You were trying to check the values of two ranges `"E2:E & LastRow"` and `"I2:I & LastRow"` in one go, but you cannot do that. You have to loop through the rows of the ranges and check each cell i.e. `"E2", "E3", "E4" ... "E" & LastRow` and `"I2", "I3", "I4" ... "I" & LastRow`. For this task a [For Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) loop can used.
- The 1st code is showing how it is done using [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range).
- The 2nd code is showing how it is done using **column strings** (letters) with [Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells).
- The 3rd code is showing how it is done using **column numbers** with `Cells`.
- The 4th code is showing how you can define the column ranges (`rng1`, `rng2`) and use `Cells` with one parameter.
- The 5th code is showing how you can define **constants** to store the so called 'magic' characters and later quickly access (change) them. It is also modified to be able to change the resulting column (`tgtCol`).
- `Range` might seem easier, but you have to learn `Cells`, too, e.g. because you cannot loop through columns using `Range`, you have to use column numbers with `Cells`.
- Study the first three codes closely, and you will learn the differences soon enough.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub fillSimpleRangeVersion()
    
    ' Calculate the last non-blank cell in column "F".
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    ' Loop through the rows from 2 to LastRow.
    For i = 2 To LastRow ' i will change: "2, 3, 4 ... LastRow"
        ' Check that current cell in column "E" is not blank and
        ' that current cell in column "I" is blank:
        ' If not E2 blank and I2 blank then,
        ' If not E3 blank and I3 blank then ...
        ' If not E & LastRow blank and I & LastRow blank then.
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("E" & i)) And IsEmpty(Range("I" & i)) Then
            ' If true, write "unregister" to current cell in column "I".
            Range("I" & i).Value = "unregister"
        ' The Else statement is not needed, because you only write when
        ' the condition is true.
        Else
            ' If not true, do nothing.
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub fillSimpleCellsStringsVersion() ' Column Strings E, F, I
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "E")) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, "I")) Then
            Cells(i, "I").Value = "unregister"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub fillSimpleCellsNumbersVersion() ' Column Numbers 5, 6, 9
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 9)) Then
            Cells(i, 9).Value = "unregister"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub fillSimpleCellsVersionWithRanges()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = Range("I2:I" & LastRow)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
        If rng1.Cells(i).Value <> "" And rng2.Cells(i).Value = "" Then
            rng2.Cells(i).Value = "unregister"
        End If
    Next i
            
End Sub


Sub fillSimpleCellsExpanded()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2          ' First Row
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "F"   ' The column to Calculate Last Row
    Const Col1 As Variant = "E"         ' Column 1
    Const Col2 As Variant = "I"         ' Column 2
    Const tgtCol As Variant = "I"       ' Target Column, the Column to Write to
    ' You want to write to the same column "CritCol2 = tgtCol", but if you
    ' want to write to another column, you can easily change "tgtCol".
    Const Criteria As String = "unregister"  ' Write Criteria
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, Col1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, Col2)) Then
            Cells(i, tgtCol).Value = Criteria
        Else
            ' The following line is only needed if "CritCol2" is different
            ' than "tgtCol".
            Cells(i, tgtCol).Value = Cells(i, Col2).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you  Loop Through Rows A Quick Fix is great code please explain the code and say me where i was wrong  your code work